# Using ShardedJedis with RedisTemplate

Tags: java, spring, redis, jedis

### Following is Jedis documentation directly copied from jedis github page:

```
List<JedisShardInfo> shards = new ArrayList<JedisShardInfo>();
JedisShardInfo si = new JedisShardInfo("localhost", 6379);
si.setPassword("foobared");
shards.add(si);
si = new JedisShardInfo("localhost", 6380);
si.setPassword("foobared");
shards.add(si);
```

Then, there are two ways of using `ShardedJedis`. Direct connections or by using `ShardedJedisPool`. For reliable operation, the latter has to be used in a multithreaded environment.

2.a) Direct connection:

```
ShardedJedis jedis = new ShardedJedis(shards);
jedis.set("a", "foo");
jedis.disconnect;
```

2.b) Pooled connection:

```
ShardedJedisPool pool = new ShardedJedisPool(new Config(), shards);
ShardedJedis jedis = pool.getResource();
jedis.set("a", "foo");
.... // do your work here
pool.returnResource(jedis);
.... // a few moments later
ShardedJedis jedis2 = pool.getResource();
jedis.set("z", "bar");
pool.returnResource(jedis);
pool.destroy();
```

---

Above example shows how to use `ShardedJedis`.

In my current setup, I am using `RedisTemplate` and `JedisConnectionFactory`.

My question is

> How do I use `ShardedJedis` with `RedisTemplate`?

Comment: This is old, but at that time, the reply says it doesn't support shards. http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/nosql/104599-how-to-connect-to-multiple-redis-instances-using-redistemplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it doesn't directly support your case. RedisTemplate offers a high-level abstraction for Redis interactions. 
While RedisConnection offers low level methods that accept and return binary values (byte arrays).

See: [Working with Objects through RedisTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:template)

Answer (score 0):

I think u can config jedis in spring.xml with below code:
and of course you should create a JedisClient.java as an interface

```
<!-- redis cluster -->
<!-- <bean id="jedisCluster" class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisCluster">
    <constructor-arg>
        <set>
            <bean class="redis.clients.jedis.HostAndPort">
                <constructor-arg name="host" value="${redis01.real.cluster.client.host}"/>
                <constructor-arg name="port" value="${redis01.real.cluster.client.port}"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="redis.clients.jedis.HostAndPort">
                <constructor-arg name="host" value="${redis02.real.cluster.client.host}"/>
                <constructor-arg name="port" value="${redis02.real.cluster.client.port}"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="redis.clients.jedis.HostAndPort">
                <constructor-arg name="host" value="${redis03.real.cluster.client.host}"/>
                <constructor-arg name="port" value="${redis03.real.cluster.client.port}"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="redis.clients.jedis.HostAndPort">
                <constructor-arg name="host" value="${redis04.real.cluster.client.host}"/>
                <constructor-arg name="port" value="${redis04.real.cluster.client.port}"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="redis.clients.jedis.HostAndPort">
                <constructor-arg name="host" value="${redis05.real.cluster.client.host}"/>
                <constructor-arg name="port" value="${redis05.real.cluster.client.port}"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="redis.clients.jedis.HostAndPort">
                <constructor-arg name="host" value="${redis06.real.cluster.client.host}"/>
                <constructor-arg name="port" value="${redis06.real.cluster.client.port}"/>
            </bean>
        </set>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="jedisClientCluster" class="com.dingli.rest.component.impl.JedisClientCluster"/> -->
```